# Find out which modules are associated with a usb device?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

Could you recommend a way to figure out which driver is being used for a USB device.
Sort of a usb equivalent of `lspci -k` command.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

## Finding the Kernel Driver(s)

### The victim device

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
Bus 010 Device 003: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply
```

We're going to try to find out what driver is used for the APC UPS. Note that there are two answers to this question: The driver that the kernel would use, and the driver that is currently in use. Userspace can instruct the kernel to use a different driver (and in the case of my APC UPS, `nut` has).

### Method 1: Using usbutils (easy)

The `usbutils` package (on Debian, at least) includes a script called `usb-devices`. If you run it, it outputs information about the devices on the system, including which driver is used:

```
$ usb-devices
⋮
T:  Bus=10 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=051d ProdID=0002 Rev=01.06
S:  Manufacturer=American Power Conversion
S:  Product=Back-UPS RS 1500 FW:8.g9 .D USB FW:g9 
S:  SerialNumber=XXXXXXXXXXXX  
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=24mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbfs
⋮
```

Note that this lists the current driver, not the default one. There isn't a way to find the default one.

### Method 2: Using debugfs (requires root)

If you have debugfs mounted, the kernel maintains a file in the same format as `usb-devices` prints out at `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices`; you can view with `less`, etc. Note that debugfs interfaces are not stable, so different kernel versions may print in a different format, or be missing the file entirely.

Once again, this only shows the current driver, not the default.

### Method 3: Using only basic utilities to read /sys directly (best for scripting or recovery)

You can get the information out of `/sys`, thought its more painful than `lspci`. These `/sys` interfaces should be reasonably stable, so if you're writing a shell script, this is probably how you want to do it.

Initially, `lsusb` seems to count devices from 1, `/sys` from 0. So 10-2 is a good guess for where to find the APC UPS lsusb gives as bus 10, device 3. Unfortunately, over time that mapping breaks down—sysfs re-uses numbers even when device numbers aren't. The `devnum` file's contents will match the device number given by lsusb, so you can do something like this:

```shell
$ grep -l '^3$' /sys/bus/usb/devices/10-*/devnum     # the ^ and $ to prevent also matching 13, 31, etc.
/sys/bus/usb/devices/10-2/devnum
```

So, in this case, it's definitely `10-2`.

```
$ cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/10-2
$ ls
10-2:1.0             bDeviceClass     bMaxPower           descriptors  ep_00         maxchild   remove     urbnum
authorized           bDeviceProtocol  bNumConfigurations  dev          idProduct     power      serial     version
avoid_reset_quirk    bDeviceSubClass  bNumInterfaces      devnum       idVendor      product    speed
bcdDevice            bmAttributes     busnum              devpath      ltm_capable   quirks     subsystem
bConfigurationValue  bMaxPacketSize0  configuration       driver       manufacturer  removable  uevent
```

We can be sure this is the right device by `cat`ing a few of the files:

```
$ cat idVendor idProduct manufacturer product 
051d
0002
American Power Conversion
Back-UPS RS 1500 FW:8.g9 .D USB FW:g9
```

If you look in 10-2:1.0 (`:1` is the "configuration", `.0` the interface—a single USB device can do multiple things, and have multiple drivers; `lsusb -v` will show these), there is a modalias file and a driver symlink:

```
$ cat 10-2\:1.0/modalias 
usb:v051Dp0002d0106dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00in00
$ readlink driver
../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usbfs
```

So, the current driver is `usbfs`. You can find the default driver by asking `modinfo` about the modalias:

```
$ /sbin/modinfo `cat 10-2\:1.0/modalias`
filename:       /lib/modules/3.6-trunk-amd64/kernel/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbhid.ko
license:        GPL
description:    USB HID core driver
author:         Jiri Kosina
author:         Vojtech Pavlik
author:         Andreas Gal
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic03isc*ip*in*
depends:        hid,usbcore
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.6-trunk-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           mousepoll:Polling interval of mice (uint)
parm:           ignoreled:Autosuspend with active leds (uint)
parm:           quirks:Add/modify USB HID quirks by specifying  quirks=vendorID:productID:quirks where vendorID, productID, and quirks are all in 0x-prefixed hex (array of charp)
```

So, the APC UPS defaults to the `hid` driver, which is indeed correct. And its currently using usbfs, which is correct since `nut`'s `usbhid-ups` is monitoring it.

## What about userspace (usbfs) drivers?

When the driver is `usbfs`, it basically means a userspace (non-kernel) program is functioning as the driver. Finding which program it is requires root (unless the program is running as your user) and is fairly easy: whichever program has the device file open.

We know that our "victim" device is bus 10, device 3. So the device file is `/dev/bus/usb/010/003` (at least on a modern Debian), and `lsof` provides the answer:

```
# lsof /dev/bus/usb/010/003 
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
usbhid-up 4951  nut    4u   CHR 189,1154      0t0 8332 /dev/bus/usb/010/003
```

And indeed, its `usbhid-ups` as expected (lsof truncated the command name to make the layout fit, if you need the full name, you can use `ps 4951` to get it, or probably some lsof output formatting options).

Comment: I'm definitely gonna loose in my ever going debate with my friend of Windows vs Linux with this one :) . Will give it a few days to see if a simpler solution pops out. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Alan OK, I've found two more ways, one of them is quite simple. Also, I've clarified which of two possible answers to "which driver?" each method provides.

Comment: I don't think your claim about locating the device in `/sys/bus/usb/devices` is correct. I have a device on bus 1 that `usb-devices` says is device 12, but there's no `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-11` on my system.

Comment: @Cerin indeed it isn't. I'll put in a better one. Thank you.

Comment: Amazing response. Thanks a lot for posting this. It was very helpful!

Comment: If nothing is listed as a driver try dmeag :)

Answer (score 28):

`lsusb` itself can get you good results.  For compact output I use `lsusb -t`, where `-t` shows the devices as a tree; this format reports the driver as well.

Example output:

```
 $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
...
```

If no driver is used, the line will look like this (the device in my example is a camera for which I did remove the driver from the kernel):

```
    |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides what derobert wrote, I find myself using

`lsusb -t`

Which will print a tree with various info about connected devices including an helpful « Driver » part.

and

`dmesg | grep driver`

which will list you the drivers of the latest plugged-in devices.

The pros is that these two commands come installed with all distributions.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use `lshw` which will enumerate the devices on all buses including USB, PCI, etc so you can see which driver it uses and its associated IDs:

```
sudo lshw
```