# driver being used by kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

I would like to check which driver is being used by the kernel for the eth0 interface.

Is `lspci eth0` the correct command ?

Comment: Not really, cause i try this command it does not show me  the driver used by the kernel for this device

Comment: You tried `lspci -k` (as mentioned in the answer associated with the first comment)?

Comment: I hope it's a real device, not for example a virtual interface in a container...

Comment: @GarryJeanPierre what did the command proposed in the [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41819/377345) show when you tried it? Can you check whether you have a `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/` directory or not?

Answer (score 1):

To identify the driver used by a particular network interface, use `ethtool -i <name of interface>` as root.

Example on my `eno1` interface (new-style naming) on Debian 10:

```
# ethtool -i eno1
driver: e1000e
version: 3.2.6-k
firmware-version: 0.5-4
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:00:1f.6
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

So, in this case, the driver is `e1000e`.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo lspci -v` shows the drivers in use for all your PCI(E) devices. `sudo` is not strictly required but might show more info.

Finding drivers for USB devices is more complicated: [Find out which modules are associated with a usb device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60078/find-out-which-modules-are-associated-with-a-usb-device)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. but what about which driver is being used by the kernel in order to use the sound card in a linux machine?